# Prevent child window from closing when parent window is closed in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm making an Electron app. This app has a way to open a new window (popup) to be dragged on a different monitor. This window has a way to open another one, and so on. I need the user to be able to close a window he does not want, but keep others open.

First, I tried `window.open` but the child window gets closed when the parent is closed. I thought it must be because the var gets garbage collected.

Second, I tried binding to the `new-window` event in the main process.
This is what I did:

```
let windows = [];

function createNewWindow(){
  let win = new BrowserWindow(
    {
      width: 1600,
      height: 900,
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
      }
    }
  );

  win.webContents.on('new-window', (event, url) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    let win = createNewWindow();
    win.loadURL(url);
    event.newGuest = win;
  })

  windows.push(win);

  return win;
}
```

But the child gets closed when the parent is closed. I checked the `windows` var, but it is correctly retained in the main process, so this should not be a GC problem.

How can I open a chain of windows (with or without `window.open`) without them being closed when the main parent is closed?

**EDIT**

As I did not found a way to keep windows open, I decided to hide the windows instead of closing them. This is what I did:

```
  win.on("close", (event) => {
    if (win.hideInsteadOfClose == true) {
      event.preventDefault();
      win.hide();
    }
  });
```

Where `hideInsteadOfClose` is a property I give to new windows created. This is not the proper way of doing it, but it gets the work done. Please feel free to answer with the correct way.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the issue is the way you're letting the Browser Context initiate the new window, instead of using the IPC thread to communicate to the main thread.

Comment: I have, as an evil, exactly the opposite situation in the 13th electron. P.s. each createNewWindow () will create a new listener to create a new window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I did not found a way to keep windows open, I decided to hide the windows instead of closing them. This is what I did:

```
  win.on("close", (event) => {
    if (win.hideInsteadOfClose == true) {
      event.preventDefault();
      win.hide();
    }
  });
```

Where `hideInsteadOfClose` is a property I give to new windows created. This is not the proper way of doing it, but it gets the work done.

Please feel free to answer with the correct way.